# jquery live for effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

```
$("#toggle-banner-body").live("click", function(){
      $("#banner-details").slideToggle();
});
```

When I click the `#toggle-banner-body` then `#banner-details` toggle doesn't works. The `#toggle-banner-body` and `#banner-details` are newly created elements, thats why I have used live function there. Is there any way to identify the `#banner-details` element? I mean how to use live function on effects.

Comment: This code LOOKS ok. Can you throw a jsfiddle up there so we can see whats happening? Also `live` is deprecated. Check out the `.on()` and `.off()` functions.

Comment: Are you able to use jsfiddle.net to give us example code?

Comment: i am having problem with only this piece of code. it is a drupal website.

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is deprecated, now with jQuery 1.7.1 you can use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on(event, selector, handler) // live
$(selector).on(event, handler)           // bind
```

---

```
$("#parent").on("click","#element", function(){
      $("#banner-details").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: when i use your code snippet it gives this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @subhojit777 are you sure you use the newest jQuery?

Comment: @subhojit777 here is a working demo using .on() like in my answer: http://jsbin.com/eyezij/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: thanks. the js file is in my drupal 7.12 website and its using jquery 1.5.2. cant the problem be solved using live function?

Comment: Go to save > download and explore locally the downloaded document. http://jsbin.com/ayumey/3/edit I used jQuery 1.5.2 and works well!

Comment: `.on()` and `.off()` were added in jQuery 1.7. If you have to use an older version, **use `.delegate()` instead**. Don't use `.live()`.

Comment: in your example when i click on any banner, the banner details appears for only the first banner. thats the problem. how to add the effect for newly created elements

Comment: @subhojit777 simple! don't use ID `#` but CLASS `.` elements! ID is unique-per-page, classes are multiple!

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan good suggestion feel free to add an *edit* to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function(){
   $("#toggle-banner-body").live("click", function(){
      $("#banner-details").slideToggle();
   });
});
```

***Notice*** that `live()` is deprecated and won't work in future versions of jQuery, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.